# Jupyter and timer functions?

Tags: python, timer, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter via Anaconda on Windows 10.

I would like to have a plot, on which a new random value is plotted each second. So far, I have this code:

```python
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import sched, time
import random
from ipywidgets import widgets

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = np.zeros(100)

fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=ys,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Random'))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 10])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 10])

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
yi = 0
def tick_func(sc):
    global ys, yi
    ys[yi] = random.random() * 10
    yi = (yi+1)%100
    fig.data[0].y = ys
    s.enterabs(time.time()+1, 1, tick_func, (sc,))
#s.enterabs(time.time()+2, 1, tick_func, (s,))
s.run()

widgets.VBox([fig])
```

The output of this code, as is, is shown on this screenshot:

[image: jupyter_tick_start]

... which is the correct starting/initial plot, as intended. The idea then is, as soon as the code has started, I would get a new random value along the x-axis, each second.

However, as soon as I enable/uncomment the `s.enterabs(time.time()+2, 1, tick_func, (s,))` line - which actually triggers the timer function to start looping - then there is simply no output (no graph drawn)! No errors, but no output either!

So, how can I get a timer function running inside a Jupyter notebook, with effects shown on a plot (here Plotly)?

I found the recommendation for `sched` here: [What is the best way to repeatedly execute a function every x seconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python) - but maybe it interferes with some of the implementation in Jupyter (or Plotly, or both?), so maybe there is something else I should use?

( possibly related, though I couldn't find much that helps me with this specific problem: [Interactive Timer in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087884/interactive-timer-in-jupyter-notebook) )

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got somewhere, thanks to these:

- [Coroutine as background job in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895256/coroutine-as-background-job-in-jupyter-notebook)
- [Launching a python script as a background job on Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925706/launching-a-python-script-as-a-background-job-on-jupyter)
- [a new thread for running a cell in ipython/jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081926/a-new-thread-for-running-a-cell-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook)

First of all, here is a reworked simple example from the link above, which shows the use of `IPython.lib.backgroundjobs.BackgroundJobManager`:

```python
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32081926/a-new-thread-for-running-a-cell-in-ipython-jupyter-notebook
##github.com/jupyter/ngcm-tutorial/blob/master/Day-1/IPython%20Kernel/Background%20Jobs.ipynb
import sched, time # NOTE: without this import, we'll get "Dead jobs:" instead of "Running jobs:" - exception at time.sleep will not be reported as such!
from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()

def printfunc(interval=1, reps=5):
    for n in range(reps):
        time.sleep(interval)
        print('In the background... %i' % n)
        #sys.stdout.flush() # flush breaks the thread in Jupyter, after first printout!
    print('All done!')
    #sys.stdout.flush()

#jobs.new('printfunc(1,3)') # works; prints: <BackgroundJob #0: printfunc(1,3)>
jobs.new(printfunc, 1, 3) # works; prints: <BackgroundJob #0: <function printfunc at 0x0000017120038730>>
jobs.status() # prints: "Running jobs:" "0 : <function printfunc at 0x00000171200389D8>" or "0 : printfunc(1,3)"
```

Here is how it looks like in Jupyter notebook:

[image: jupyter_background_jobs_01.gif]

That lead finally to getting the OP example to work - simply, by having the `scheduler.run` be called through `jobs.new`:

```python
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import sched, time
import random
from ipywidgets import widgets

from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
ys = np.zeros(100)

fig = go.FigureWidget()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=xs, y=ys,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='Random'))
fig.update_xaxes(range=[0, 10])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, 10])

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
yi = 0
do_run_tick_func = True
def tick_func(sc):
    global ys, yi
    if do_run_tick_func:
        ys[yi] = random.random() * 10
        yi = (yi+1)%100
        fig.data[0].y = ys
        s.enterabs(time.time()+1, 1, tick_func, (sc,))
    else:
        print("Exiting tick_func (not recheduling)") # this does not print on page
#s.enterabs(time.time()+15, 1, tick_func, (s,))
#s.run() # kills widget

#s.run()
#jobs.new(s.enterabs, time.time()+2, 1, tick_func, (s,)) # Does not run in loop, but says: Completed jobs: 0 : <bound method scheduler.enterabs of <sched.scheduler object at 0x000001E01CF12978>>

#jobs.new(tick_func, s) # runs once, does not loop: Allo 0; Completed jobs: 0 : <function tick_func at 0x0000017120038400>

s.enterabs(time.time()+1, 1, tick_func, (s,))
jobs.new(s.run) # runs in loop! Running jobs: 0 : <bound method scheduler.run of <sched.scheduler object at 0x0000017120058390>>
#jobs.status() # prints: "Running jobs:" ...

# https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Events.html
output = widgets.Output()
mybuttonstop = widgets.Button(description="Stop Background Thread")
mybuttonstart = widgets.Button(description="Start Background Thread")

def on_button_stop_clicked(b):
    global do_run_tick_func
    print("Button clicked - stopping background thread...") # this does print on page
    do_run_tick_func = False
    with output:
        print("print, with output?") # this does not print on page

def on_button_start_clicked(b):
    global do_run_tick_func
    print("Button clicked - starting background thread...") # this does print on page
    do_run_tick_func = True
    s.enterabs(time.time()+1, 1, tick_func, (s,))
    jobs.new(s.run)

mybuttonstop.on_click(on_button_stop_clicked)
mybuttonstart.on_click(on_button_start_clicked)

myhbox = widgets.HBox([mybuttonstart, mybuttonstop])
widgets.VBox([myhbox, fig])
```

Here is how this looks like in Jupyter notebook:

[image: jupyter_background_jobs_02.gif]

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that the code cell which displays a widget must finish executing before the widget will display.

What you need is a way for the widget to call back to the Python kernel after it has initialized in order to request an update.
You could implement this using proxy widgets like this.

[image]

You can also combine proxy widgets with other widget types using HBox, etcetera and use the proxy widget for timing purposes as shown above.

Please see https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget and the discussion of asynchronicity of widgets in the Tutorial notebook.

Comment: Thanks for this - as far as I can see, here JavaScript takes over controlling the timer function (even if the timer function code is defined in Python); in my answer below, it is Python that still controls the timing. Many thanks for the pointer to the asynchronicity of widgets discussion, was not aware of that!